# How can I prevent Web NFC from crashing Chrome when navigating between routes with the NDEFReader object?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, nfc, webnfc

I am using the Chrome Web NFC API in a web app that runs on Android 13 in Chrome 110 to scan NFC tags. Chrome crashes when I navigate between routes that contain a component with the NDEFReader object and 'ndef.scan' call.

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Navigate to the official web NFC sample content https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-nfc/
2. Click the 'Scan' button
3. Scan an NFC tag
4. Now click the 'Scan' button again
5. Notice that the browser crashes

**Full Code Example:** https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/blob/gh-pages/web-nfc/index.js

**Description of Problem** When I navigate to a route containing a component that instantiates the `NDEFReader` object and then calls `ndef.scan()`, I can scan an NFC tag as expected. However, when I navigate away to the home screen and then back again, the web app crashes when it calls `ndef.scan()`.

```
const ndef = new NDEFReader();
await ndef.scan();
```

**Cases where the web app doesn't crash:**

- If I refresh the page in the browser before I call ndef.scan again it will not crash.
- I can call scan as many times as I want as long as I don't physically scan a container before calling scan again.

**Chrome Web NFC Documentation:** https://developer.chrome.com/articles/nfc/

**Update**

- Replicable on Android 13, Chrome 110, (last OS security update Feb 5, 2023), Pixel 6
- Replicable on Android 13, Chrome 111, (last OS security update Feb 5, 2023), Pixel 6
- NOT replicable on Android 13, Chrome 110, (last OS security update Aug 5, 2022), Pixel 4
- NOT replicable on Android 13, Chrome 110, (last OS security update Oct 5, 2022), Pixel 4

**Bug submitted on the Chromium bug tracker. Upvote it here:** https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1424208

Answer (score 0):

As shared in https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1424208#c6, the root issue seems similar to https://b.corp.google.com/issues/238257723 where a new SecurityException is raised on connect().

You can follow fix in progress in the chromium bug tracker: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1424208

**March 27th, 2023 Update:**
As of [Chrome 113.0.5672.0](https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/commit/510313f0c84548dc115f4951b334f7495eec5470), the issue has been solved.